# Show full text input in Visual Studio Code R terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I have R extension on my Visual Studio Code and open R terminal. If I input long string of characters the line becomes cut by the `$` sign. I have tried different word-wrapping and similar settings without luck, how could I see the whole terminal inputs? The PowerShell terminal does wrap the input to multiple lines.